# How to use beautiful soup returned list make a new html?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

soup.find_all('a') function will return a list.

for example

```
'''
> # [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
> #  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>,
> #  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>]
'''
```

I want to use this list to make a html file.

if i use for loop it will display only one character ony bye one.

is  there anyway to make list as

```
'''
> # <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>
> # <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>
> # <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>
'''
```

delete the `[` and `,` after the `</a>` and `]`

Comment: show your loop code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just out put as string and join them:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>
<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>
<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
alpha = soup.find_all('a')

to_html = ''.join(str(a) for a in alpha)
print (to_html)
```

The `''.join()` is basically doing this:

```
# Initialize a variable that is an empty string
to_html = ''

# Iterate through that list
for a in alpha:
   #join the to_html string with a as a string
    to_html = to_html + str(a)
```

Comment: thank you this works may i know what's the meanning of join(str(a) for a in alpha) in here what's the meaning of "a" in the str and for "a" which part of python guide should i looking for?

Comment: it takes each element in your list (the `find_all('a')`, turns it into a str, and then joins them with no space. I'll expand that out into a for loop to make it more understandable.

Comment: so str(a) == <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a> ?

Comment: a+a+a give me the result <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a><a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a><a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>

Comment: yup. more or less, that's essentially the idea.